# mysql daemon crawling - incredibly slow

Tags: mysql, performance, daemon

I have no idea what happened - one moment my mysql daemon is running fine, the next it's locked solid, queries through the daemon are timing out on a 60 second wait.

I've tried rebooting, server and daemon both. I've looked in the error logs and there's nothing. CLI is working fine, no problems. HTTP is fine, Apache reporting no problems. It's just the daemon that's gone on strike and I have no idea why.  Frustrating.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: the server RUNS as a daemon, so not sure what this "server and daemon" bit is...

Comment: is your server showing a high CPU or I/O usage?

Answer (score 0):

install [heidisql](http://www.heidisql.com/) and look what's pulling the instance down when it starts to drown.

this screen will help you finding the list of instances and what they ae doing at the moment.

http://www.heidisql.com/screenshots.php?which=host_processlist

Comment: Server as in Centos server. And HeidiSql doesn't appear to do a Linux version?

Comment: can you remote connect to that centos server on a win system with heidisql?

Comment: I think the command was SHOW PROCESSLIST which it was using to get that list. Can you try that?